# Why does Plot of Table uses the same color rather than Plot of explicit List?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

The command

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

plots

[image]

i.e. different functions plotted with different colors.

Simultaneously

```
PlotF[f_List] := 
 Plot[Table[g[x], {g, f}], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
PlotF[{Sin, Cos}]
```

plots

[image]

What is this about `Table` function I forgot? Is there any `Table` equivalent in Mathematica, which behaves more intuitive?

Comment: Use `Evaluate` in the first argument of `Plot`:, i.e., `PlotF[f_List] := Plot[Evaluate@Table[g[x], {g, f}], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]`

Comment: I think the linked topic and links it contains should answer you well, let me know if you disagree.